# Failing to Get-AzureStorageTable due to missing dependency System.Spatial

Tags: powershell, azure-table-storage, azure-powershell

I'm trying to Get an azure table by running the following command:

`Get-AzureStorageTable -Name  <tablename>`

And I'm getting:

`Get-AzureStorageTable : Could not load file or assembly 'System.Spatial, Version=5.8.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. Th
specified. HTTP Status Code: 200 - HTTP Error Message: OK
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-AzureStorageTable -Name  <tablename>
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-AzureStorageTable], StorageException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : StorageException,Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.Table.Cmdlet.GetAzureStorageTableCommand`

Although the error is very explicit I'm new to Powershell and I'm trying to figure out how to fix this issue.

1. Is it correct to assume that Powershell Get-AzureStorageTable takes its dependencies from Nugets under *.nuget* folder?
2. What is the source of this issue? I would expect the dependency to be there.

Comment: I've got the exact same problem, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I also met the same problem, I resolved it by load the **System.Spatial.dll(Version=5.8.1.0)** from code. I also upload the **System.Spatial.dll** to [github](https://github.com/wxtom/AzureTestCode),you could download it to your local path example: `c:\test`. You also could get the demo from it.

```
$ctx = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccount -StorageAccountKey $storageAccountKey
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("path of System.Spatial.dll") | Out-Null # example: c:\test\system.spatial.dll
$table = Get-AzureStorageTable -Name $tableName -Context $ctx
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I'm told, this is caused because you are running 5.0.0 of the storage modules. If you update Azure.Storage to anything beyond 5.0.0, it'll fix this issue. It is recommended to simply get the latest version of AzureRM, which will have all of the updated modules/dependencies.

FYI, I'm part of the Azure PowerShell API team, but I only started 3 weeks ago, so I'm not at the point where I know the history of these issues and such. :-P